# Error SQL: La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
alter PROCEDURE hola
as
declare @setHoraInicioCita datetime
declare @setHoraFinCita datetime
declare @horaincio datetime
declare @horafin datetime
declare @tmpromedio datetime
declare @idespecialidad int
set @horaincio = (select HoraInicio = CONVERT (time, HoraInicio,120) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @horafin = (select HoraFin = CONVERT (time, HoraFin,120) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @tmpromedio = (select TiempoPromedioAtencion = convert(char(8), dateadd(minute, TiempoPromedioAtencion, ''), 114) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @idespecialidad = (select IdEspecialidad from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
begin
truncate table cupos
end
while @horaincio < @horafin
begin
set @setHoraInicioCita = @horaincio;
set @horaincio = @horaincio + @tmpromedio;
set @setHoraFinCita = @horaincio;

insert into cupos (horainicio,horafin,idespecialidad) values (@setHoraInicioCita,@setHoraFinCita,@idespecialidad)

end

select * from cupos
```

y aquí muestra los cupones que hay en cada fecha de cada programación medica.

cuando hay mas de 1 programaciones en la misma fecha me sale el siguiente error:

```
La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.
```

Pero si solo tiene una programación, esto funciona normalmente.
Necesito urgentemente una ayuda

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que esperas obtener?

Comment: ¿Digamos, cuando hay más de una _programación_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya se comentó, el problema es que las subconsultas regresan más de un valor cuando se busca obtener un valor escalar. Sin embargo, el problema anterior es que estás queriendo usar T-SQL como un lenguaje procedural en vez de pensar en conjuntos.

Para solucionar un problema así, lo mejor es utilizar una tabla de números (o *tally table* en inglés) que pueda generar todos los cupos en una sola instrucción. Esto lo podemos convertir en una función tipo tabla.

```
CREATE FUNCTION generaCupos(
    @horainicio datetime,
    @horafin datetime,
    @tiempoPromedio int
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF( MI, @horainicio, @horafin)/@tiempoPromedio + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))* @TiempoPromedio n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT DATEADD( MI, n - @TiempoPromedio, @horainicio) AS horainicio,
       DATEADD( MI, n , @horainicio) AS horafin
FROM cteTally;
```

Con esta función, el procedimiento se vuelve mucho más sencillo.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE hola(
    @Fecha datetime
)
AS
INSERT INTO cupos (
    horainicio,
    horafin,
    idespecialidad
) 
SELECT c.horainicio,
    c.horafin,
    pm.IdEspecialidad
FROM ProgramacionMedica AS pm
CROSS APPLY dbo.generaCupos( pm.HoraInicio, pm.HoraFin, pm.TiempoPromedioAtencion) AS c
WHERE Fecha = @Fecha;
```

Y así se insertan los cupos para todas las especialidades de una fecha con una sola instrucción y sin usar bucles o cursores que solo harán más lento el código.

Comment: Eres el mejor bro, me has ayudado demasiado, solo modifique unas cosas y funciona al 100 x 100

Answer (score 1):

El problema que se te presenta es que haces subconsultas para obtener unas fechas en:

```
set @horaincio = (select HoraInicio = CONVERT (time, HoraInicio,120) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @horafin = (select HoraFin = CONVERT (time, HoraFin,120) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @tmpromedio = (select TiempoPromedioAtencion = convert(char(8), dateadd(minute, TiempoPromedioAtencion, ''), 114) from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
set @idespecialidad = (select IdEspecialidad from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000')
```

Alguna de estas subconsultas te está devolviendo más de 1 valor, por lo tanto no puede poner los 2 o más valores en la variable que estás intentando llenar, y entonces te devuelve el error.

Deberías comprobar que las consultas que estás haciendo sólo devuelvan el valor que a ti te interesa modificando los `WHERE` para que se cumpla lo comentado.

Answer (score 0):

> from ProgramacionMedica where Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000'

Tienes varias entradas en 'ProgramacionMedica' con esa fecha. Parece claro que quieres introducir un registro en 'cupos' por cada registro de 'ProgramacionMedica'. Usa un cursor.

```
alter PROCEDURE hola
as
declare @setHoraInicioCita datetime
declare @setHoraFinCita datetime
declare @horaincio datetime
declare @horafin datetime
declare @tmpromedio datetime
declare @idespecialidad int
DECLARE workCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT HoraInicio = CONVERT (time, HoraInicio,120), HoraFin = CONVERT (time, HoraFin,120), TiempoPromedioAtencion = convert(char(8), dateadd(minute, TiempoPromedioAtencion, ''), 114), IdEspecialidad FROM ProgramacionMedica WHERE Fecha = '2019-02-26T00:00:00.000'
OPEN workCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM workCursor;
INTO @horaincio, @horafin, @tmpromedio, @idespecialidad
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @setHoraInicioCita = @horaincio;
set @horaincio = @horaincio + @tmpromedio;
set @setHoraFinCita = @horaincio;
insert into cupos (horainicio,horafin,idespecialidad) values (@setHoraInicioCita,@setHoraFinCita,@idespecialidad)
END
CLOSE workCursor;
DEALLOCATE workCursor;
```